# Using NLP to clean up user generated content automatically?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, nlp, semantics

Is it possible to use NLP to automatically improve user generated content?

The goal is to take a bad UGC sentence like:

`no low beams or running lights..bulbs ok and high beams work!!!`

And try to improve it into something like:

`No running lights or low beams. Bulbs are alright and the high beams are working!`

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

First, you would have to parse the sentence and extract the part of speech tags. For this I recommend the Stanford parser (I do encourage you to look for alternatives though).

For a better understanding of my answer, type the first sentence in the online version of the Stanford parser:  http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process

Go "Collapsed CC-processed dependencies" and look at the dependency tree.

In essence, what you would have to do is spot a pattern in the dependency tree and then modify it accordingly. In this case for instance you would have to find `ok <- [amod] <- beams <- [dep] <- bulbs`, check if `bulbs` is plural and replace `ok` with `are all right`. If `bulbs` would be **`bulb`** (singular) then you would have to replace it with `is all right`.

The problem is that you would have to spend a lot of time writing rules to spot patterns in dependency trees, and even more time to handle them the way you want.

An even bigger problem is that the sentence isn't clean by default, which makes it hard for a parser to parse it accordingly.

For the example you have provided, a less robust but easier solution would to simply replace `ok` with `is / are all right` if the word that precedes it is a noun at singular / plural. The difference is that you would not be using the dependency tree, but I have a feeling this is prone to errors. I am also not sure how well it might extend to other example and not just the ones you have provided (as they are both pretty much the same).

Answer (score 0):

It's an open research problem. People realized that normalization is very helpful when analyzing tweets, youtube comments, etc.

On a research level, here's the first article I found: [Normalization of Dutch User-Generated Content](http://www.lt3.ugent.be/en/publications/normalization-of-dutch-user-generated-content/).

Checking in their references, there's also this: [A Phrase-based Statistical Model for SMS Text Normalization](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/P/P06/P06-2005.pdf?q=lingoes). They seem to look at the problem from a machine translation point of view - translate from user generated content to proper English.

On a more practical level I haven't tried many things, the one I've been using is [GATE's twitter module](http://gate.ac.uk/wiki/twitie.html). They have a normalization algorithm but I think it's very simple - just replaces things like "idk" with "I don't know".